# Issue with installing DeGruyter fonts

Tags: fonts, texshop, installing-fonts

I am trying to install fonts that are necessary to successfully compile a De Gruyter template using dgruyter.sty. I ran into issues when trying to compile the document. This is the error message:

```
! I can't find file `DGMetaSerifScience-Regular-tlf-t1'.
<*> ...de; input DGMetaSerifScience-Regular-tlf-t1
                                                  
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...de; input DGMetaSerifScience-Regular-tlf-t1
                                                  
Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: DGMetaSerifScience-Regular-tlf-t1.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input DGMetaSerifScience-Regular-tlf-t1' failed to make DGMetaSerifScience-Regular-tlf-t1.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

./book.tex:56: Font T1/DGMetaSerifScience-TLF/m/n/8.0=DGMetaSerifScience-Regula
r-tlf-t1 at 8.0299pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.56 \maketitle
```

I am using TexShop on Mac.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are the fonts publicly available?

Comment: I don't think they are, since I had to log into the author portal to download them. The fonts are called De Gruyter's DG Meta Science/Serif Science. The dgruyter.sty is on Github.